# Combine Group Data from duplicate rows into single rows and sums

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched for an answer to this and I have see how to do this when you have only single lines of data.  I have a report that the data is on 2 lines.  I have looked at pivot tables but it doesn't like multi rows like that.  I need a guiding hand on what direction to look, even if its VBA which I have tried but I am just running into the issue of excel knowing the data is on 2 separate lines.  The first to lines of each are grouped together.  I will highlight in different colors in my example.

[image: Image of Worksheet]

I guess I could have the macro take all the data and combine the two rows into one and then run a pivot table but was hoping I wouldn't have to go to that extreme.  Any help would be great or a point in the right direction to help get me started.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go on a copy of your data

```
Public Sub CombineRows()
    Dim DescriptionCol As Long, HeaderRow As Long, NoRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    HeaderRow = 6
    ' Change this to your sheet
    With Sheet1
        'Change this to your starting column (looks like B in the pic)
        DescriptionCol = 2
        NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, DescriptionCol).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = NoRow To HeaderRow + 1 Step -2
            With .Cells(i, DescriptionCol)
                .Offset(-1, 0).Value2 = .Offset(-1, 0).Value2 & ": " & .Value2
                .Value2 = vbNullString
                ''Uncomment below to delete unused lines
                '.EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very close.  I just need it to bring the 2nd line's cell up to the first line.  As it is right now it moves the first cell down to the 2nd line's cell